# react native ScrollView - snap scroll to next/previous stickyHeaderIndices

Tags: javascript, react-native

when i scroll up, i want the ScrollView to snap scroll to the next sticky header, and when scroll down it should snap to the previous sticky header. I have multiple `stickyHeaderIndices` in ScrollView. How can this be achieved.

The offsets should be dynamic. The `<Text>` component can have different heights. Eg.

Text can be short like

```
<Text>lorem ipsum</Text>
```

or Text can be

```
<Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem accusantium
              placeat aperiam similique velit quia, eum temporibus labore consequatur aut corporis
              eos aspernatur nostrum dolorum magni doloremque itaque provident veniam ea tempore
              officiis. Rerum quasi soluta iure eveniet odit, eligendi architecto dicta eius! Fugit
              minus obcaecati sequi accusantium, quibusdam ex consequatur quas quisquam totam.</Text>
```

I have something like this

```
<ScrollView
 onScroll={(event) => {
  code here
 }}
 decelerationRate="fast"
 snapToStart={false}
 disableIntervalMomentum={true}
 stickyHeaderIndices={[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]}
 snapToEnd={false}>
    <Text>Header</Text> // intially load here
    <Text>lorem ipsum</Text>
    <Text>Header</Text> // scroll to here
    <Text>lorem ipsum</Text>
    <Text>Header</Text> // scroll to here
    <Text>lorem ipsum</Text>
    <Text>Header</Text> // scroll to here
    <Text>lorem ipsum</Text>
    <Text>Header</Text> // scroll to here
    <Text>lorem ipsum</Text>
    <Text>Header</Text> // scroll to here
    <Text>lorem ipsum</Text>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There is no need to do code other than this. You just have to pass the index which you want to be sticky. It will automatically manage it.

Comment: @HarshKukarwadiya the header is sticky but i want the content to snap to different offsets, and the offsets have to be dynamic

Comment: Can you please provide any photo or Video?

Comment: @HarshKukarwadiya i got it to work. you need to use measure on the layouts and save the offsets to usestate.